# Session lost after AJAX request (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony, fetch

I have shopping cart where I'm adding items via AJAX (fetch). When I add item to cart and check request in debug toolbar, the session is correctly set. But after page reload, the session disappear. It it strange because when I use same code for adding item to cart but not via AJAX (using link and redirect), everything works fine. Where could be a problem?

```
public function addItem(int $id, string $type, int $quantity = 1)
{
    $item = new CartItem();
    $item->setId($id);
    $item->setQuantity($quantity);
    $item->setType($type);
    $this->items[] = $item;
    $this->session->set(self::SHOPPING_CART_SESSION_NAME, $this->items);
}


/**
 * @Route("/add-to-cart", name="add_item_to_cart")
 */
public function addItemToCart(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

    $type = $data->type;
    $id = intval($data->id);
    $quantity = intval($data->quantity);

    $this->shoppingCartService->addItemToShoppingCart($id, $type, $quantity);
    return new JsonResponse('success', 200);
}


fetch('/add-to-cart', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        type: type,
        id: productId,
        quantity: quantity
    })
}).then((response) => {
    response.json().then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `cookie_httponly` to `false` in your configuration? That makes the session cookie accessible to javascript as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-httponly).

Comment: @Philippe-B- Yes, but it did not help.